# how to remove the v4l2sink plugin after upgrading obs studio?

Tags: obs-studio

Going back to using OBS Studio after a very loooooong while, I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04, and reinstalled OBS Studio as per [the latest instructions](https://obsproject.com/download):

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ffmpeg obs-studio
```

When starting it, it shows this message window shown below. It's probably looking at old settings/configuration directories used by the old installation. But I can't spot any files named v4l2 through File -> Show Settings Folder, and am quite very reticent to start freestyle hacking things.

[image]

This error survives apt uninstalling and reinstalling obs-studio.

How can I remove that plugin, which is no longer needed as its functionality has been integrated into OBS Studio many versions ago already?

---

Or perhaps more broadly, how would I clean up any trace of any settings from the old installation of OBS Studio, in order to reinstall it without OBS Studio finding this plugin or any past configuration and setting from earlier versions and use of OBS Studio at all?

Comment: P.S. OBS Studio is just so awesome.